# Pandas fillna across chunks

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a huge SQLite db that when read into pandas in a single chunk would cause a memory error. The usual way to work around is to set a `chunksize` parameter:

```
db = 'rawdb.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
SQL = 'SELECT * FROM Table'

df = pd.read_sql(SQL, conn, chunksize=10000)
```

I am trying to clean the data in the db (2mil rows x 141 columns), by:

1. Dropping any row with more than 32 `NaN` values
2. Forward fill all other `NaN` values of rows not dropped

I can extract the data I need if it was a single chunk:

```
df[~(df.isnull().sum(axis=1) > 32)].fillna(method='ffill')
```

**How do I accomplish this across chunks?** Specifically, since `chunksize = 10000`, the next chunk would start from 10001 data onward, and if row 10001 happens to contain `NaN` values and the row is not dropped, it is suppose to ffill from row 10000.

However, row 10000 is in a previous chunk, so there is no reference for ffill. This would result in row 10001 `NaN` values not being filled. What is the template algorithm to get around this kind of problem?

Comment: Why not clean with those two steps at the end after reading all chunks?

Comment: Now that your question is answered, can you answer mine? Is it a performance issue to not clean at end?

Comment: It's not a performance issue. You simply can't read the whole file into memory because it is too big, so you read them part-wise (by chunks),  manipulate and store it, unload the current chunk and read the next one.

Comment: That is not my question. I understand the chunk process. I am questioning your cleaning process. Why iteratively clean and not do all at once at end?

Comment: What did you mean by 'after reading all chunks'? I assumed you meant loading all chunks to memory but I think i'm understanding you wrong. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: I am basically asking why aren't you segmenting your proces into two steps? 1) Run `df = pd.read_sql(SQL, conn, chunksize=10000)` and then after all data is read 2) Run: `df[~(df.isnull().sum(axis=1) > 32)].fillna(method='ffill')`

Comment: @Parfait, but the full df doesn't fit in memory, so how can you clean it all at once? Usually you'd read in a chunk, perform some aggregation on it, save the results of this aggregation and discard the chunk itself. Then move on to the next chunk and repeat.

Comment: Can we confirm that by OP? It's the read process that takes up memory as it is an i/o process. I have used chunks to read in very large datasets and then from there use the full dataset for other work.

Comment: Yes, loading the entire data set causes memory error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When iterating over chunks you could save the last row from previous iteration and use that to fill missing values in the first row of new chunk. Example:

```
lastrow = pd.Series() # initialize with empty Series
for chunk in pd.read_sql(SQL, conn, chunksize=10000):
    chunk = chunk[chunk.isnull().sum(axis=1) <= 32]
    # fillna for the first row
    chunk.iloc[0,:] = chunk.iloc[0,:].fillna(lastrow)
    # fillna for the rest
    chunk.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
    # do something with chunk
    # ...
    # save last row for next chunk
    lastrow = chunk.iloc[-1,:]
```

Comment: Technically a column is a `pd.Series` and a row is a `pd.DataFrame` due to mixed data types.